# Regex for alphanumeric, comma, hyphen, period - Address validation

Tags: regex

So far I have the following regex plus event keys for address validation:

Updated with Regex that works based on comment below:

```
const ADDRESS_REGEX = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\s.,'-]*$/;

addressValidation(event){
if (!ADDRESS_REGEX.test(event.key) && event.key !== "Tab" && event.key !== "Delete" && event.key !== "Backspace" && event.key !== "ArrowLeft" && event.key !== "ArrowRight" && event.key !== "Enter" && event.key !== "NumpadEnter"){
  return false;
 }
}
```

It works correctly except it is blocking periods. How can I update the regex to allow periods? An even larger question, is alphanumeric, comma, hypen, period correct for address validation?

Question #2

How can the above regex be modifed to check for numbers followed by word or word followed by number. Example:
"33 random street" or
"9 West 57th Street"

Comment: Add it - `/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s.,'-]*$/`

Comment: Using `key` property of `event` object, you can't guarantee it works on mobile devices.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Your answer works. In addition, how would you update your answer to check letters with space and then numbers and vise versa?

Comment: Could you provide some examples? It sounds like another question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew updated original question

Comment: Note sure really, try `^(?:[a-zA-Z]+|[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]*)(?:[\s.,'-](?:[a-zA-Z]+|[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]*))*$`. See https://regex101.com/r/q6LoSE/1. Maybe https://regex101.com/r/q6LoSE/2. Your requirements are vague for the second "request".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s.,'-]*$/
              ^
```

The dot inside a character class will always match a literal dot, no need to escape it.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NAQUVi/1).

Note @revo's comment about potential problems with using the `key` property of `event` object (one can't guarantee it works on mobile devices).

For the second part of the question, you may try

```
^[^\W_]+(?:[\s.,'-][^\W_]+)*$
```

See the 9regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/q6LoSE/3)

Comment: "Block"? If a string contains `'`, return no match/false? Remove it from the pattern :). `/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s.,-]*$/`